# How do I fetch guild owner Id in discordjs v13?

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to fetch the guild owner Id's of the servers my bot is currently in.
Everything I try returns undefined.

Current owner fetching from cache. I also tried guild.fetchOwner()

```
let owner = client.users.cache.get(guild.ownerID);
  if (typeof owner !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(owner)
  } else {
    console.log("Couldn't get owner!")
  }
```

My for of loop:

```
for (const [id, guild] of client.guilds.cache) {}
```

Comment: It's `guild.ownerId` with lowercase `d`

Comment: Thank you. However that was a typo from typing it here. It's correct in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys! However I figured it out.

I moved this function to my ready event to ensure that the client had time to login. That is why it was returning undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Guild.fetchOwner`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchOwner) method fetches the owner from the API and always returns the owner.

```js
let getOwners = async () => { 
  let owner = await guild.fetchOwner().catch(err => err)
  return owner
}
getOwners().then(owner => {
  if(owner !== undefined){
    console.log(`ID: ${owner.user.id}\nUsername: ${owner.user.username}`)
  }
})
```

**What is happening?**

> - I created a async function called `getOwners()` that will fetch the owner of the current guild in the for loop.
> - then I called the function and if the returned owner !== undefined, you can do what you'd like with that.

I used an example of console logging the returned user data, just to show you some of the stuff you can access with the returned owner.

Comment: with this, you don't need a for loop. if this is coming from an interaction just switch `message` to `interaction`

Comment: Its not ran with a command. Its saving data. So I will not find this in the message or interaction. I need this to loop through all the guilds

Comment: okay lemme see what i can get to work and then edit the answer for u

Comment: i got it working and updated my answer, lmk how it goes!